# Message about missing } in \int_case:nn

Tags: expl3, latex3

I get

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.47     Test $\Id$
                   , $\Id{A}$ and $\Id{A,B}$ inline.
```

when compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:n #1
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nn
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
          \mathop{Id}
        }
        {1}
        {
          \mathop{Id}_{#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
          \mathop{Id}
            ^{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
            _{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {
          msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than one argument for {\backslash}Id}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {shmuel} {short} {\#1}
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {\#1} {\#2}
%Should it be ## rather than \#?
\ExplSyntaxOff

Test $\Id$, $\Id{A}$ and $\Id{A,B}$ inline.
\begin{equation}
  Test \Id, \\
   \Id{A}, \\
   \Id{A,B}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I changed the argument specifier to {O{{}}} and changed the incorrect braces in the \Id invocations to brackets. Better, but now the default value is take a {} rather than an empty clist, the _ is taken as a text character rather as a subscript and [A,B] is treated as a single token rather than as a list of two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{\{\}}}
  {
     \Id:n #1
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nnF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
          \mathop{Id}
        }
        {1}
        {
          \mathop{Id}_{#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
          \mathop{Id}
            ^{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
            _{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {
          msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than two arguments for {\backslash}Id}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {shmuel} {short} {\#1}
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {\#1} {\#2}
%Should it be ## rather than \#?
\ExplSyntaxOff

Test $\Id$, $\Id[A]$ and $\Id[A,B]$ inline.
\begin{equation}
  Test \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[A,B]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `\Id` with an optional argument defaulting to nothing so

```
 $\Id$
```

is

```
$\Id:n $
```

so gets `$` as the argument after which everything goes wrong, you need to pass `\Id:n{#1}`  with braces to ensure that `#1` gets passed on intact.

I'm not sure of the intention of all the code but this runs without error other than the expected error when passed a list of three.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:n {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nnTF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}
        }
        {1}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}\sb{#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
          \mathop{\mathrm{Id}}
            \sp{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
            \sb{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {}
      {
          \msg_error:nnn {shmuel}{long} {#1}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {more\ than\ two\ arguments\ for\ \string\Id: #1} {help}
\ExplSyntaxOff

Test $\Id$, $\Id[A]$ and $\Id[A,B]$ $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}] $ inline.
\begin{equation}
  Test \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[A,B]
\end{equation}

\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Id {O{}}
  {
     \Id:n {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \Id:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \int_case:nnF
      {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
      {
        {0}
        {
         \operatorname{Id}
        }
        {1}
        {
         \operatorname{Id} \sb {#1}
        }
        {2}
        {
         \operatorname{Id}
           \sp {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 1}
           \sb {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 2}
        }
      }
      {
          \msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than two arguments for {backslash}Id}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {shmuel} {short} {##1}
\msg_new:nnnn {shmuel} {long} {##1} {##2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test $\Id$, $\Id[A]$ and $\Id[{A,B}]$ inline.
\begin{equation}
  \text{Test} \ \Id, \\
   \Id[A], \\
   \Id[{A,B}]\\
   \Id[A,B,C]\\
\end{equation}

%Test $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}]$

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_error:nn {shmuel} {More than two arguments for {backslash}Id}

\end{document}
```

giving an error

```
! Package shmuel Error: more than two arguments for \Id:{too},{many},{parms}
```

Comment: I tried to fix the code to reflect your comments (see edit), but it's treating [A,B] and [{A,B}] as a list of one token, it's still not taking the default to an empty clist and it's not treating _ as a subscript request. Note that the calls to \Id are in Math mode.

Comment: @shmuel you need `[A,B]` as you defined an optional argument and `\sub` and `\sup` (or their l3 equivalents) for sub/super scripts as `_` is a normal letter in expl3 code sections.

Comment: @shmuel no! your edit makes it worse, do not introduce `\{`  !! I meant you need `\Id:n {#1}` not `\Id:n #1` but also please don't edit partial answers into the question it makes the post very hard to understand later,

Comment: It now sort of works, but Id renders in italic; wrapping it in \mathrm fixes that.

Comment: I tried testing my error code; pleas see my latest edit for the TeX error message I got.

Comment: @shmuel should be `\mathop{\mathrm{Id}` not `\mathrm{\mathop{Id}}` or better `\operatorname{Id}` as you are loading amsmath

Comment: Yes, \operatorname{Id} gives the same output as \mathrm{\mathop{Id}} and is clearer. That still leaves the question of why I get "! Missing \endcsname inserted." when I try to test the false leg of the case.

Comment: @shmuel please revert all the edits you have made to the question, the error in the message is the mis-use of the math command `\backslash` the code I posted yesterday does not use that and runs without error and answered the question as originally stated,

Comment: @shmuel "`\operatorname{Id}` gives the same output as`\mathrm{\mathop{Id}}` and is clearer." No they give different  output. `\operatorname{Id}` has mathop spacing.

Comment: That version still has problems issuing the message. Also, I don't understand why  \int_case:nnTF rather than  \int_case:nnF. One problem is that I left out the message parameter after the module name, but after I fixed that it still doesn't issue the message properly: I get ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__iow_wrap_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.55     Test $\Id[{too},{many},{parms}]
                                        $
?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95162/discussion-between-shmuel-and-david-carlisle).